# Can't change Tomcat 9 JDK when running as a Windows service

Tags: windows, tomcat

My Windows 10 already have `JAVA_HOME` set as environment variable pointing to JDK8. But I want to run this Tomcat 9 with OpenJDK 12.

I download [Tomcat 9 64-bit zip](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-90.cgi). When I run it manually via `startup.bat`, all I need to do is create `bin\setenv.bat` and put the new value of `JAVA_HOME` there as stated in the RUNNING.txt that accompanies the package.

But, if I install Tomcat as a service using `service.bat install MyService` it uses the `JAVA_HOME` of Windows, which is expected.

The problem is when I try to follow [these instructions](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/windows-service-howto.html#Updating_services) to update my installed service and change the Java home.

I tried this with no success:

```
>tomcat9.exe //US//MyService --JavaHome=path\to\openjdk
```

I'm doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When installing tomcat service I should do:

```
service.bat install MyService --rename
```

After, I execute `MyServicew.exe` and change the JVM in the java tab.